# bash — поставить перенос строки после первого слова

Tags: linux, bash

Возможно ли в `bash` после первого слова в файле поставить `перенос строки` ? 
Слово может быть разной длины, поэтому считать символы и ставить перенос после символов не предлагать.

Comment: да, возможно (хотя проще использовать более специализированную программу типа *sed/awk*).

Comment: Чисто шеллом тяжело будет, с cut уже проще

Comment: эм.. `echo ololo blablabla | sed "s: :\n:"`?

Comment: Ловите: `cat | while read a b; do echo $a; if [ "x$b" != "x" ]; then echo "$b"; fi; done`

Answer (score 2):

`sed` вас точно спасет

```
echo "first second third"|sed 's/ /\n/'
```

Comment: А если после первого слова `\t`, а не пробел?

Comment: echo "first second third"|sed 's/[ \t]/\n/'

Comment: А если перед первым словом пробел?